# Firestore only works in some parts of my code?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if you had run into a similar problem like the one that I am experiencing now:

I am building an Android project using Java in Android Studio. I am using Firestore as the database for storing and retrieving the data for the Android front end. I started building this project last Friday. On the first day of the project, I used the following way to make query:

```
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userCollectionRef = db.collection("users");
Query userQuery = userCollectionRef.whereEqualTo("email", getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
userQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
           for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                  User newUser = document.toObject(User.class);
                  //Do something there
           }
}}}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("why fail", e.toString());
        }
});
```

Where the User class is defined as:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String major;
    String email;
    String password;
    String ID;
    String photo;
    boolean isActive;
    boolean isManager;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

And the Firestore database looks like this:
[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUG2r.png)

On the first day of the project, the query was working perfectly. But ever since that day, whenever I use the SAME query in a different Activity (EXACTLY THE SAME: I copied and pasted this code to a different Activity to obtain the same User info), Firestore stops returning ANY results.

The weirdest part is that, Firestore query is still working in the Activities that were implemented on the first day of the project. I tried to see if Firestore logged anything in Logcat but there was none?!

As the result, I ended up using the following way to make query which was very dumb, but it is the only way that is working at this point:

```
Task<QuerySnapshot> task = db.collection("users").get();
while (!task.isComplete()) {
    //Wait for finish
}
//Loop through documents to check for match
for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()) {
    if(d.toObject(User.class).getEmail().equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("email"))){
          userDocumentReference = d.getReference();
          User newUser = d.toObject(User.class);
          //Do something here
          break;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if someone can shed some light on what I should do to resolve this issue? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same email address as in the first activity from your Intent object?

Comment: Yes, I am very positive!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not to define firebasefirestore instance in another activity then they are crashed ....or if I am wrong then please show full activity crashed means crashed activity code

Comment: Thanks for your input. I declare a firebasefirestore instance in every activity where I need to make query. Could you please elaborate on "crashed activity code"? I just tried to create a brand new Activity with this single piece of code from my original post, and it still does not work. I tried to log it but Logcat did not catch anything...